# What does "Did you save room for dessert?" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning, spoken-english

What does "Did you save room for dessert?" mean? I'm an English learner. I don't know what this sentence means, especially the "save room" part. Please describe its meaning for me.

Comment: Where did you see this sentence?  In a textbook? Which textbook?

Comment: It seems to just follow the literal meaning of the words. Did you try to look up both those words in a dictionary? Note that [questions that can be answered by a quick dictionary lookup are out of scope for this site](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). The only unstated part here is where you're supposed to save room.

Comment: @NotThatGuy: I'm new here, and maybe don't understand the norms.  But I don't see this as a dictionary lookup.  I'm a native English speaker and certainly understand the phrase.  But trying this with dictionary definitions doesn't seem to help.  What does rescuing a walled partition of a building have to do with dessert? Or is this supposed to do with laying up of money?  Is "room" supposed to the crowd present at an indoor event?  Even if you get to "room" as empty space, and "save" as preserve, how would you make the leap to "stomach"?

Comment: you will also see room used in terms of space for things like 'do you have room for one more?' or 'we have room for one more if you want to come'  which is talking about having space for another person (eg for a trip or another seat at a table).

Comment: @ScottSauyet Looking something up in a dictionary doesn't mean stopping at the first definition, it means checking various ones until you find one that makes sense. So that definitely should lead one to "save room = preserving empty space". I wouldn't know where else you would need room for food, but if they got stuck there, that's probably fair enough, it's just that the question doesn't demonstrate that. "If you are asking about the meaning of a word or phrase, you should look up those words in a dictionary first. If you are still confused, be sure to summarize what you found..."

Comment: @NotThatGuy: While the question should have given more information about meanings tried and rejected, I do think you're glossing over the fact that "preserving empty space" is only one possibility of many, and it doesn't immediately lead to "in your stomach". Equally valid would be "on the table", and we could come up with others.  And any answer found this way would probably miss the important point of the tact in the question mentioned in gunfulker's answer.

Comment: @ScottSauyet But without any other context (which is why I assumed that James K asked what he did in the first comment) the phrase works equally well whether the asker is referring to "in your stomach" or "on the table". Context is needed. Did you save room for dessert ... (or are you full?) or Did you save room for dessert ... (it's a large pie and might not fit on the table)

Comment: @CGCampbell: Sure, but it's a common enough English question -- at least in my part of America -- that has a consistent meaning.  You'd probably get funny looks if you used it in reference to how full the table is.  My point was that simple dictionary lookups aren't really enough to explain the meaning here.  Although it's less severe, it's similar to noting that one will never understand "kicked the bucket" just with standard definitions of "kicked", "the", and "bucket".

Answer (score 34):

"Save" is being used to mean "put away for later". "Save" is often used this way when referring to money "Saving up to buy a car", or if someone wants you to share "save some for me".

"Room" is being used to mean "empty space". When entering a large gymnasium, one might say "there is a lot of room in here".

So "Did you save room for dessert?" is literally asking if you kept some space empty in your stomach for dessert, but it usually means they are offering you dessert.

It's a tactful way of offering because it allows someone to say "no, I'm full" if they don't want dessert.

Comment: "Save" is also used to mean "rescue", the meaning is a little similar. "He rescued the hostages (from their fate)" "He rescued his money (from being spent)". "Room" is also used to mean a division within a house, usually separated by doorways or stairs. It originally meant space, but at some point it became common to refer to rooms as "dining room", "living room", "bed room", and generically any space within the house as "a room"

Comment: A single-word synonym for this sense of "save" is "reserve".

Comment: @gunfulker This sense is far removed from "rescue".

Comment: @Barmar Take it up with user "Janus Bahs Jacquet" in his answer here: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/230596/etymology-of-save-in-the-meaning-of-except-but-unless

Comment: @gunfulker Janus Bahs Jacquet's answer is far removed from this question.  Yes, "save" and "room" have the senses of "rescue" and "division in a house", but those senses are not relevant here.  Your answer is excellent; your comment detracts from it.

Comment: @TimSparkles People are more than capable of looking up the definitions of common words on their own, but questions like this come when they're used in multiple ways. I really doubt this question would exist if the words had only one usage. Since I identified that as the crux of the confusion, I deemed it relevant to include the other common usages and how they related to the relevant usage in a comment where it would be available, without bothering anyone.

Answer (score 16):

It means, "Are you too full to eat dessert?"

Here is a definition from [The Free Dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/save+room+(for)):

> To refrain from eating too much so that one still has an appetite for something else later on.

Comment: One of the definitions of [room](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/room) is "an extent of space [...] available for something."  This phrase is asking whether you've saved space within your stomach for dessert by not eating too much for dinner.

Comment: Also, if said by a waiter, this is also a way of asking "would you like to order dessert?"

Comment: Not even just said by a waiter... in fact, I've never heard someone say this in a context other than offering dessert.

Comment: @Brad the same concept is used in things like 'do you have room for 1 more?' and things like that.

Comment: in food terms, it is mostly used to talk about room for desert, but you will occasionally see it used to refer to courses in general: https://ounews.co/education-languages-health/education/festive-feast-always-room-another-course/ `It’s Boxing Day and you have munched enough chocolate, pudding, and turkey to sustain you for another twelve months; however, there is always room for another course.`